# ClassNotFoundException when running fat JAR configured by spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to create executable JAR file for my spring boot application.
To achieve this spring-boot-maven-plugin has been used with main class specified and packaging to jar.
Unfortunately after running output JAR file i receive java.lang.ClassNotFoundException pointing to my main class.

Below is my pom.xml and main class. Thanks in advance for help.

**pom.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>interflight</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>interflight</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <feign-gson.version>7.2.1</feign-gson.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.0</gson.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.8.0</assertj-core.version>
   <startClass>com.test.interflight.configuration.InterflightApplication</startClass>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!--External dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${feign-gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    <!--Test dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <layout>ZIP</layout>
          <mainClass>com.test.interflight.configuration.InterflightApplication</mainClass>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Output error:**

```
    $ java -jar interflight.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.interfl
ight.configuration.InterflightApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(Laun
chedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLau
ncher.java:587)
```

**Main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.interflight.controller", "com.test.interflight.implementation.*"})
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.test.interflight.api.restclient"},
                    defaultConfiguration = FeignConfiguration.class)
public class InterflightApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InterflightApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: what package is the main class in? what is the package statement at the top of the InterflightApplication class file?

Comment: You could just remove the `<mainClass>...</mainClass>` block in your `pom.xml` because the spring boot maven plugin will search for a main class by itself.

Comment: @Scigs main class is located in `package com.test.interflight.configuration;`

Comment: @FlorianCramer you're right but in this case such action results in `Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class`

Comment: @Macieyo It Seems your Fat Executable is ZIP not JAR. Please have a look at spring docs to Run Spring Boot Application with ZIP https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html

Comment: My bad indeed, unfortunately changing to JAR is still not a problem.. The strange thing is that application is quite simple so default configuration should work properly, unnecessarily I started to complicate things during tries of solving the problem..

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Looks like you're using the `ZIP` layout when you should be using the `JAR` layout. Change `<layout>ZIP</layout>` to `<layout>JAR</layout>` in your Spring Boot maven plugin declaration.

**Longer answer:**

Take a look at [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) which describe the `ZIP` layout as:

- `ZIP` (alias to `DIR`): similar to the `JAR` layout using
  `PropertiesLauncher`.

And of which the `PropertiesLauncher` is [described in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html) as:

- Launcher for archives with user-configured classpath and main class
  via a properties file...
- Looks in various places for a properties file to extract loader settings, defaulting to application.properties...  No default, but will fall back to looking for a **Start-Class in a MANIFEST.MF**

If you want it to be user specified in your Jar file, specify (or check and see if you have one already) in the `meta-inf` folder of your Jar, or specify the property yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answer, indeed `ZIP` wasn't the best choice as my intention is to receive pure `JAR` file. During attempts of solving problem I left it unnecesarly..
Anyway after changing layout to `JAR` I have the same error, MANIFEST.MF paths appear to be rather fine.
**MANIFEST.MF**
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.test
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.test.interflight.configuration.InterflightApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_92`

Comment: Gotcha. Can you post the file paths in your `web-inf/classes` directory inside your JAR?

Comment: That's interesting, I don't have such folder inside my JAR. It contains structure as folows:
`BOOT-INF/lib`,  `META-INF/maven/com.test/interflight/pom.properties&pom.xml`,  `META-INF/manifest.mf,  org/springframework/boot/loader/archive&data&jar&util&some_class_files`

Comment: Maybe it is important - my project structure includes separation to logical parts represented by directories, there is implementaion, controller, api and configuration with standard layout inside: `src/main/java/com.test.interflight.(API/CONTROLLER/CONFIGURATION/IMPLEMENTATION)` (depending on folder). There is only one maven module with parent pom.xml including aforementioned folder structure.

Comment: I think it's a red flag if you're seeing a `/src/main/java` folder in there... It should be finding your runnable inside of the `meta-inf/classes` folder. Has your `pom.xml` changed from what you have in your original post?

Comment: Not much, actually only `<layout>` of package in spring-boot-maven-plugin has changed to `JAR` instead of `ZIP`

Answer (score 0):

After several days dealing with various plugins, finally I could make a fat jar (spring boot) with externalize config files everywhere I wanted to be. You can use the following plugins:"config" is the path for your config files next to the jar file.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>jarfilename</finalName>
                    <mainClass>com.start.YourStarter</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                        <exclude>deploy/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.txt</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.start.YourStarter</mainClass>
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
   </plugin>
```